# If $f'(x) = \sin{\frac{\pi e^x}{2}}$ and $f(0)= 1$, what is $f(2)$?

Tags: calculus

If $f'(x) = \sin{\dfrac{\pi e^x}{2}}$ and $f(0)= 1$, then what will be $f(2)$?

This is what I tried to find the antiderivative of $f'(x)$ with u-substitution,

$$
\begin{align}
u &=\frac{\pi e^x}{2} \\
\frac{2}{\pi}du &=e^x dx
\end{align}
$$

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are you sure that you have copied the problem correctly?

Comment: @mrf - Yes I am pretty sure I copied it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts: Apply mean value theorem to $f$ on the interval $[0,2]$ to obtain:

$$ \frac{f(2) - f(0)}{2} = \sin (\frac{\pi e^c}{2}) $$

for some $c$ in the interval. Then, we have that $f(2) = 2 \sin (\frac{\pi e^c}{2}) + 1$

[image]

Comment: So what do I do with the $c$? And when I plug in $2$ or $0$ into $c$, both does not seem to give me a correct answer.

Comment: I used the Laplace Transformation to solve this, but cannot get a better answer than you gave here. In fact, we need to solve $\int\frac{\sin k}{k}dk$ for some $k$.

Comment: $c$ lives in the soul of the interval. Therefore, $c$ cannot be $0$ or $2$.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: From Citizen solution, one can get $f(2)\in [-3,3]. $

Comment: I added a graph for the OE with initial condition. I hope you don't mind. If you don't like it, remove it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ {f'(x) = \sin{\frac{\pi e^x}{2}}}\implies \int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt = \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\frac{\pi e^t}{2}\right) $$

$$\implies f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\frac{\pi e^t}{2} \right)dt $$

$$ \implies f(2)=1+\int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi e^t}{2} \right)dt \longrightarrow (*)$$

$$=1-{\it Si} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}  \right) +{\it Si} \left( \frac{1}{2}\,{{\rm e}^{2}
}\pi  \right)  \sim 1.157117528,$$

where $Si$ is the [sine integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Derek: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

another option.. you could go with  a taylor expansion of sin(x) take the integral, and get  f(2) [in form of an infinite series].

Answer (score 0):

To get result from Mean Value Theorem we have to make sure that the sine function in the last step is $\ge 0$. The argument of sine function lies between $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. From there we can get $x$ lies between $-\infty$ to $0$. If $x$ lies between $-\infty$ to $0$ then min value of sine function is $0$ and max value is $1$. In this way we can make sure that sine function is greater than $0$. I am not sure though.